# How to extend NuxtRuntimeConfig interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am adding a variable in nuxt `$config` variable like in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config#runtimeconfig). This works.

I am trying to let typescript know about this change.

In my `nuxt.config.js` I have :

```js
// nuxt.config.js. This is to add the variable
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseUrl: process.env.URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
  }
```

I tried to extend the interface like this

```js
// vue.shim.ts
declare module '@nuxt/types' {
  interface NuxtRuntimeConfig {
    baseUrl: string
  }
}
```

However vscode still does not pickup the change

```js
const { $content, route, $config } = useContext()
console.log($config.baseUrl) // typescript does not no about baseUrl, but it exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there!

The module you have to use to trigger the interface merging is actually the path to the types file. So here, it's @nuxt > types > config > runtime.d.ts

```js
declare module '@nuxt/types/config/runtime' {
  interface NuxtRuntimeConfig {
    baseUrl: string
  }
}
```